# How to access a property of a ViewModel from another ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF project using MVVM. I have two views: `ClientView` and `CommentView`.

In `ClientView` after selecting a client  in a DataGrid I open a screen with the `CommentView`.

How do I access the property `Client` on `CommentViewModel`?

Note: The property `Client` belong to `ClientViewModel`.

Comment: Why you need that? looks like wrong design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- if CommentViewModel and ClientViewModel strongly coupled you can use it direct
- if the CommentView visual tree has anywhere the datacontext from the ClientViewModel you can use RelativeSource Binding to get there
- you can use MEF for Export the "Client" property and Import it in the CommentViewModel
- you can use some sort of Messenger or EventAggregator to communicate from your CommentViewModel to your ClientViewmodel

and some more i think :)

Answer (score 1):

pass reference of `ClientViewModel` or `ClientViewModel.Client` to `CommentViewModel` when creating it.