# reference the same instance of a view model into multiple view models

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i have an instance of a view model and 3 other view models, each of those three view models need to access the ObservableCollection of that view model, that view model is not my main view model, should i send the instance of that view model by reference to the constructor of other view models and add it as a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it shouldn't be there to begin with (if 3 other ViewModels need it to).

You could reference the ViewModel, or better yet, move that collection to your Model, or to a global resource.

**Edit:**

If you're not using any frameworks, you might have to jump through loops to do it, or pass references in the constructors.
Have a look at these answers: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459940/how-to-access-one-viewmodels-object-in-another-viewmodel-in-wpf-application-usi) , [another similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258781/how-to-access-a-property-of-a-viewmodel-from-another-viewmodel) .

I still believe you should just move it out of the ViewModel to a different place, since the ViewModel is basically a translator from your Model, to your View. If your collection is shared by different ViewModels, it should be in a shared location.

If you would have used Mvvm-Light, the Locator might have been useful, or another option would have been to use the messenger maybe, even though I wouldn't have done it that way...

Comment: i need a view model for it because the user will be able to change it, so when changes are made to that collection i need it to reflect them on the other view models, but i am not sure how to reference the view model into other view models, is it by sending it by reference to the other viewmodels constructors and setting a property in each view model to it?

Comment: Are you using any frameworks?
Mvvm-Light for example has a ViewModelLocator which you could use.
Otherwise, just create a variable of the ViewModel type you need in your other ViewModel?